# Image_Picker_For_Web no puedo subir la imagen a firestore

Tags: flutter

**Este Es Mi Codigo**

```
    import 'dart:ui';
    import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:social/MyHomePage.dart';
    
    class NuevaPublicacion extends StatefulWidget {
      String US;
      NuevaPublicacion(this.US);
      @override
      _NuevaPublicacionState createState() => _NuevaPublicacionState();
    }
    var _image;
    class _NuevaPublicacionState extends State<NuevaPublicacion> {
      var muestra;
      var file;
      final Titulo = TextEditingController();
      final Descripcion = TextEditingController();
      String Crea = DateTime.now().day.toString() + "/" + DateTime.now().month.toString() + "/" +DateTime.now().year.toString() + " " +
          DateTime.now().hour.toString() + ":" +DateTime.now().minute.toString();
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            title: Text('Nueva Publicacion'),
          ),
          body: Center(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 500,
                      child: TextField(
                          maxLength: 60,
                          controller: Titulo,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                          obscureText: false,
                          autocorrect: true,
                          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                          cursorColor: Colors.black,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Titulo",
                              hintStyle:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)),
                              helperText: "Titulo de la publicacion",
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    width: 1,
                                  )),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    width: 1,
                                  )))),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                    ),
                      _image == null?
                          Image.asset('assets/mundogris.png',height: 200,):
                          Image.network(muestra,height: 100,),
                    OutlinedButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          ElegirImagen();
                        }, icon: Icon(Icons.image_outlined,
                      color: Colors.black,),
                        label: Text('Elegir Imagen',style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black
                        ),
                        )
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 500,
                      child: TextField(
                          maxLength: 500,
                          maxLines: 10,
                          controller: Descripcion,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                          obscureText: false,
                          autocorrect: true,
                          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                          cursorColor: Colors.black,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Descripcion",
                              hintStyle:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)),
                              helperText: "Descripcion de la publicacion",
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    width: 1,
                                  )),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    width: 1,
                                  )))),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
            onPressed: () async {
              if(!Titulo.text.isEmpty || !Descripcion.text.isEmpty
              || !_image == null
              ){
                UploadTask UT = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(
                    'Fotos de =>' + widget.US).child(Crea).putFile(_image);
                var url = await (await UT).ref.getDownloadURL();
                var _imageUrl = url.toString();
                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('Familia')
                    .doc(widget.US).collection('Publicaciones').doc(Crea)
                    .set({
                  'Titulo': Titulo.text,
                  'Imagen': _imageUrl,
                  'Descripcion': Descripcion.text,
    
                });
                Titulo.clear();
                Descripcion.clear();
                _imageUrl = " ";
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return MyHomePage(widget.US);
                  }, //fullscreenDialog: true,
                ));
              }
            }, label: Text('Publicar',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
            tooltip: 'Subir Publicacion...',
            icon: Icon(Icons.upload_outlined,color: Colors.white,),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Future<void> ElegirImagen() async {
        final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
        var image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
        setState((){
          _image = image;
          muestra = image!.path;
        });
      }
}
```

**ESTE ES EL ERROR**

> Error: Expected a value of type 'File', but got one of type 'XFile'

---

Veo la imagen correctamente asignada al widget que tiene q mostrarla en pantalla pero cuando quiero subirla a cloud firestore me da ese error.
busque otros paquetes de picking images pero todos tiene diferentes formatos de archivo ninguno de los que vi para WEB me resuelve el problema de tener que convertir el formato que devuelven en file par apoder subirlo, sera que no estoy usando el codigo correcto para subir la imagen a firestore?

mil gracias por leerme.

Comment: El problema es que la [nueva api de image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#migrating-to-082) pasa a utilizar XFile pero Firebase espera File. Entonces seguramente debas usar [XFile](https://pub.dev/packages/xfile) para transformarlo antes. Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: me da el error del null safety cuando instalo el paquete de XFile por eso estoy buscando alguna otra forma de parsear la imagen de XFile a File

Comment: **Lo Resolvi cambiando el metodo ElegirImagen:**
Future<void> ElegirImagen() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

    if (result != null) {
      _image = result.files.single.bytes;
    }
**y en el upload en vez de putFile uso putData**